# Can a regression formula be Y=A - BX

Tags: regression

I'm new to statistics and I ran into this question, what I know is $Y=A + BX$ but in the question the value of $B$ is negative, is it normal for the $B$ value to be negative?

Here is the question, you don't have to answer it, I just added as a reference.

Estimate the value of $Y$ when $X = 30$ for the following regression equation:
$Y = 6.2 - 1.4 X$.

Answer (score 7):

$B = -1.4$ for you: $Y = 6.2 + (-1.4)X$. What this means is that same as if it were $+1.4$: that for every one-unit change in $X$, there is a $B$-unit change in $Y$. In this particular case, the change is that, for every one-unit change in $X$, $Y$ decreases by $1.4$ units.

$B<0$ is certainly acceptable. Consider a relationship like expected snowfall tomorrow as $Y$ and today's temperature as $X$.

Comment: Your snowfall-temperature example is wrong, apart from that relation being very nonlinear, consider temperature $-15^\circ\text{C}$, there will not be snowing. Increase temperature with 10 degrees, expected snowfall will increase!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have negative weights. The simplest example of when this would happen is when you have a factor that has a negative correlation to the output Y. This would imply for every X unit increase, there should be a corresponding B * X decrease in Y. In your example, for every unit increase of X, Y should decrease by a factor of 1.4